# The priorities of giving donation

Tags: zakat, money, eid

I wonder what is the best manner to donate money, especially in these holy days, should donations be given as important amount, or it could be divided to reach the maximum of persons, as a result the persons would receive little amounts of money.

Also i would like to know which donation is better :

- giving donation to help others buy sheep for Eid el Adha.
- giving donation to families who do need more basic needs, like scholar needs ...
- giving donation to build a mosque.

Answer (score 2):

I would say just one thing, look around yourself that what is important? Is it necessary to have a mosque in your area? Or is it important to save life of hungry people around you which are starving? or some thing else.

Just look around your self. Find the best deserving person in your view. And give your donations to that one. Because Your deeds depends up on your thinking/thoughts.